# Why does my POST reques result in a 404 error?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I've been struggling to submit a post request from my react app to my Django rest framework api: keep on getting this error:

> 404 not found Cannot POST /api/tokens/

I am using redux to handle state and post the data to my django api running on `localhost:8000`:

```
export const addToken = (company_name, name, address, supply, holders) => {
  return dispatch => {
    let headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
    let body = JSON.stringify({company_name, name, address, supply, holders,});
    debugger
    return fetch("/api/tokens/", {headers, method: "POST", body})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(token => {
        return dispatch({
          type: 'ADD_TOKEN',
          token
        })
      })
  }
}
```

In webpack.donf.dev.js:

```
const publicPath = 'http://localhost:3000/';

const publicUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/';
```

and here is my url.py:

```
from contract import endpoints

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(endpoints)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    url(r'^', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),

]
```

and the endpoint.py

```
from contract import views
from .api import TokenViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('tokens', TokenViewSet, 'tokens')



urlpatterns = [
    url("^", include(router.urls)),
    path('tokens/', views.TokenList.as_view()),
    path('tokens/<int:pk>/', views.TokenDetail.as_view()),
    path('users/', views.UserList.as_view()),
    path('users/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
]
```

Not sure if this is enough info as I am pretty new to React.js

*UPDATE*

Here is my settings.py

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
            'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
            'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.dev.json'),
        }
}
```

then webpack-stats-dev.json:

```
{"status":"done","publicPath":"http://localhost:3000/","chunks":{"main":[{"name":"static/js/bundle.js","publicPath":"http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js","path":"/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/python-projects/smart-contract-distributor/vestvault/web_interface/dist/static/js/bundle.js"},{"name":"main.d66a743648ca15de12df.hot-update.js","publicPath":"http://localhost:3000/main.d66a743648ca15de12df.hot-update.js","path":"/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/python-projects/smart-contract-distributor/vestvault/web_interface/dist/main.d66a743648ca15de12df.hot-update.js"},{"name":"static/js/bundle.js.map","publicPath":"http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js.map","path":"/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/python-projects/smart-contract-distributor/vestvault/web_interface/dist/static/js/bundle.js.map"},{"name":"main.d66a743648ca15de12df.hot-update.js.map","publicPath":"http://localhost:3000/main.d66a743648ca15de12df.hot-update.js.map","path":"/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/python-projects/smart-contract-distributor/vestvault/web_interface/dist/main.d66a743648ca15de12df.hot-update.js.map"}]}}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `fetch` base URL as `localhost:8000`? To me it seems you are requesting your front-end dev server.

Comment: That's what I thought too but I follow a tutorial at: http://v1k45.com/blog/modern-django-part-1-setting-up-django-and-react/ and he basically linked up django so that it listens to 3000. Here I updated my question

Comment: Then it seems you gotta hit your client/browser on `localhost:8000` not `localhost:3000`.. Because python/django is running on 8000 and "proxying" the front-end under it.

Comment: Yeah makes sense man but the tutorial says otherwise...